# Multiple extensions in one application

Tags: ios-app-extension

I added multiple extensions (same type) into my application, but I can't use them from the Host-application because Host-app seen only one extension. This extension name is same as application name.

I have next question: Is it possible to show and use all contained extensions?

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What type of extenxion do you mean?

Comment: Photo Editing Extension

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try multiple photo editing extensions inside one app, but in case of custom keyboard extensions I needed to **uninstall my hosting app** or go to **iOS Simulator/Reset Content and Settings...** menu in the simulator. After that I was able to see all my extensions, but that's only the analogy deduction that I can apply to your question...